# Not finding any downloadble for the openpyxl to install

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an requirement where I have to deal with excel to store webpage data,but not finding any downloadable package to work with Python 2.7.

[openpyxl](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/index.html)

Any help in this regard?

Comment: Have you tried `easy_install` or `pip install` ?

Comment: @JonClements Please put your suggestion as your answer. so that I can vote you up!

Comment: That's okay - I think it's just what most people would try before asking - I was just checking that you'd tried that first...

Comment: @JonClements  Yeah,actually over that site also they didn't mentioned to install packages with `pip` or `easy_install`. but here in the site i didn't find any such,thus asked.I am very new to this platform Sir  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get source via mercurial repository:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl
```

and then

```
cd openpyxl/
python2.7 setup.py install
```

Does the work for you?